# SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER increase or break sql query into chunks

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to automate a Python script with a batch file, and the code works fine on my own computer but runs into an operational error "too many SQL variables" when I run it with the batch file on a remote desktop.
This is apparently because the limit on a sql query is 999 parameters, and mine has more than the limit. How do I actually increase this limit or break the data into chunks of 999 cols? I came across many posts saying to increase this limit at compilation but I don't know how to do so, and the to_sql has a field called chunk but that's for rows and not columns.I'm using SQLite
My python code to insert data is:

```
df.tail(1).to_sql("table", sqlcon, if_exists="append", index=True)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you should considering having more than 999 columns. If you show us your schema, we may be able to help.

Comment: Yes I've thought about that, but for this purpose, because the rows are basically dates and the column names are securities that we need to store stuff for, I don't think I can really change it.

Comment: Sounds like a simple join table will solve that. Give it an ask.

Comment: You don't want to be [the person who lost thousands of COVID cases because they encoded too many columns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUp8pkoeMss&list=WL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schema with more than 999 columns should probably be rethought. That said, here's how to work around it.

You can upgrade to SQLite after 3.32.0 when SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER defaults to 32766. And if you need more than that, you are not allowed to design databases.

Otherwise, if for some reason upgrading is not an option, the hard coded limits can only be *lowered* at runtime. If you want to raise them you will have to recompile SQLite with a higher SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER. This will make your program difficult to deploy using standard dependency managers.

---

> Yes I've thought about that, but for this purpose, because the rows are basically dates and the column names are securities that we need to store stuff for, I don't think I can really change it.

This is a job for a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
create table securities (
  id integer primary key,
  symbol text not null unique,
  name text not null
);

create table security_prices (
  security_id integer not null references securities(id),
  retrieved_at datetime not null,
  price integer not null
);

select symbol, price
from security_prices sp
join securities s on s.id = sp.security_id
where retrieved_at = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll think about the joins. I downloaded version 3.33 sqlite3.dll and put it in the same folder as the DB Browser for SQLite, but how do I get the database to use this version? I checked which version I'm importing in my code and it seems to be 3.32.3

Comment: @activexplor3 With SQLite there is no separate database server. Your program uses the SQLite library to work on SQLite files. Each program will need to use the upgraded DDL, that includes your Python SQLite library. I'm not a Windows nor Python person, sorry.

Comment: It is using version 3.32.3 but still displaying the same operational error..

Comment: @activexplor3 What says 3.32.3? Python or your DB Viewer? It's Python that has to. Check with `select sqlite_version();`.

Comment: Sorry to bring this post back up, but now I am trying to replace the sql table with a new table that has over 2000 columns. I don't think I can do if_exists = "append" since the new rows don't have the corresponding columns in the old sql table. How do I compile SQL to increase the number of cols allowed? Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: @activexplor3 Over 2000 columns is going nowhere good. I'd recommend asking a question about redesigning your schema.